# Android 26 returns only one path Context.getExternalFilesDirs()

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage, android-storage

I was testing Pixel with 21, 23, 29, 30 API emulators and they would return two paths (first is external built-in sdcard and second is external removable sdcard) when using `getExternalFilesDirs(null)` method:

- `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.*.*/files`
- `/storage/13F6-3510/Android/data/com.*.*/files`

But then I tried to use Pixel with 26 API and I only got one path:

- `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.*.*/files`

Then I found another method to get all storages paths which returns something new to me, usually it would start with `/storage/` but now it starts with `/mnt/media_rw/`:

- `/storage/emulated/0`
- `/mnt/media_rw/1D13-0D17`

Method to get it using `StorageManager`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    val storageManager = context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
    val storageVolumes = storageManager.storageVolumes
    if (!storageVolumes.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        for (storageVolume in storageVolumes) {
            val volumePath = getVolumePath(storageVolume) ?: continue
            result.add(File(volumePath))
        }
    }
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private fun getVolumePath(storageVolume: StorageVolume): String? {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
        return storageVolume.directory?.absolutePath
    try {
        val storageVolumeClazz = StorageVolume::class.java
        val getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath")
        return getPath.invoke(storageVolume) as String
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

You can see that this method even uses reflection for API < R (30)

So I got this path `/mnt/media_rw/1D13-0D17` for Pixel 26 API. I don't understand why there is difference from other APIs.

But this path is not accessible yet, I can't read it. Then I tried to use some popular Files Browser/Explorer apps from Google Play and I found out that they request some permission to get access to such external removable storage:

[image]

[image]

I've never seen something like this before. How do they do it and why it even exists?

I have real devices with 21, 23, 29, 30 API and none of them need to use such method to access external removable storage, I can just use `getExternalFilesDirs(null)`. The same works for Pixel emulators with the same API

So where does `/mnt/media_rw/*` come from and how to request permission to access it from my app and why do I even need to grant this permission if for other APIs I don't need to do it?

I can't find any information about it at official Android documentation

Comment: Can Pixel devices use removable micro sd cards? I think they have no card slot.

Comment: @blackapps so is this emulator issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > So I got this path /mnt/media_rw/1D13-0D17 for Pixel 26 API. I don't understand why there is difference from other APIs.
> > But this path is not accessible yet, I can't read it. Then I tried to use some popular Files Browser/Explorer apps from Google Play and I found out that they request some permission to get access to such external removable storage:

I found such paths unreadable and unlistable too.

But why other apps can? I think they cannot too using the File class.
They will use Storage Access Framework.

For instance SDK 27 is Android O.

For Android N, O and P your app can create an access intent with:

```
volume.createAccessIntent()
```

Please try.

Comment: Yes, it works. Now I have to understand if I need this feature or not. How many real devices can work with removable micro sd cards only using SAF and not File?

Comment: Dont know, but i think very little. I never saw this before. I only saw /mnt/media_rw for usb-otg drives. And you used an emulator. Try on a real Pixel.